# Error when executing SQL-Query from Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I always get an error when executing this script:

> Incorrect syntax near '@values'

I have the following function to execute my SQL statement:

```
$Server = "Server"
$Database = "Database"
$i = 0

    function ExecuteSQLQuery(){

    $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $Connection.ConnectionString = "server='$Server';database='$Database'; trusted_connection=true;"
    $Connection.Open()

    $query = @
"INSERT INTO [Database].[dbo].[Folder](FolderPath,UserGroup,Permission,AccessControllType) VALUES @values
"@
    $command = $connection.CreateCommand()
    $command.CommandText = $query
    $command.Parameters.Add("@values", $values) 
    $command.ExecuteNonQuery()
}
```

And this is the rest of the code in which I am getting the Data for the INSERT

```
$RootPath = "\\server\folder1\folder2\folder3"
$Folders = dir $RootPath -recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}

#root folder permission

$ACLs = get-acl $RootPath | ForEach-Object { $_.Access }

Foreach ($ACL in $ACLs) {
       #Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $OutFile
        $FolderPath = $RootPath
        $User = $ACL.IdentityReference
        $Permission = $ACL.FileSystemRights
        $AccessControllType = $ACL.AccessControlType

        if($i -gt 50) {
            Invoke-sqlcmd @params -Query $InsertResult
            $i=0
            $values = ""
        }
        elseif($i -eq 0) {
            $values += "('$FolderPath','$User','$Permission','$AccessControllType')"
            $i ++
        }
        else {
            $values += ",('$FolderPath','$User','$Permission','$AccessControllType')"
            $i ++
        }
}

#subfolders

foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {
       $ACLs = get-acl $Folder.fullname | ForEach-Object { $_.Access }

       Foreach ($ACL in $ACLs) {
          $FolderPath = $Folder.Fullname
          $User = $ACL.IdentityReference
          $Permission = $ACL.FileSystemRights
          $AccessControllType = $ACL.AccessControlType
          $IsInherited = $ACL.IsInherited

          if ($i -gt 50) {
             ExecuteSQLQuery
             $i=0
             $values = ""
          }
          elseif ($i -eq 0) {
             $values += "('$FolderPath','$User','$Permission','$AccessControllType')"
             $i ++
          }
          else {
             $values += ",('$FolderPath','$User','$Permission','$AccessControllType')"
             $i ++
          }
       }
}
```

I am new to Powershell so I don't now if the error is because of my code or if the `$values` contains something Powershell or SQL can't handle.

Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: The error is telling you the problem, `INSERT INTO {Table Name} ({columns}) VALUES @values` isn't value syntax. You need to pass the values you are inserting inside parenthesis and the same amount as in the `INSERT` clause. For example `INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES (@Value1, @Value2, @Value3)`.

Comment: @Larnu I thought this works if I write the `(value1, value2, value3)` Part in the parameter. Ok thanks. Do you know a way to insert multiple values at once as I have tried it here?

Comment: *"Do you know a way to insert multiple values at once as I have tried it here?"* Exactly the way I have shown you. You can't use a variable/parameter to replace part of code. SQL isn't a scripting language.

Comment: @Larnu I don't mean to insert multiple values, I mean to insert multiple rows like ´VALUES(value1, value2, value3),(value1, value2, value3)´. Sorry that was my mistake. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: Exactly as *you* have shown, @Mikey . There are even examples in the documentation: [inserting multiple rows of data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-inserting-multiple-rows-of-data)

Comment: If you want to insert multiple rows into a table at once then you probably want to populate a `System.Data.DataTable` and then invoke [`Write-SqlTableData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/write-sqltabledata?view=sqlserver-ps) on it.

Comment: Or you could use SQL Bulk Copy, [Powershell sample](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PowerShell/blob/master/Invoke-SQLBulkCopy.ps1)